np.load() takes too much memory
I'm very new to python and machine learning in general and been working with a school-related project recently. I'm currently stuck with this code block as it is been taking too much memory space when I load my npy files.
features_list = []
labels_list = []

for i in range(9221):
    npy_path = f'E:/padFrames/video_{i}.npy'
    frames_array = np.load(npy_path, mmap_mode='r')
    
    # Append frames to the features list
    features_list.append(frames_array)

    # Extract labels for the current video
    labels = df.iloc[i][categoryEmotions].values
    labels_list.append(labels)

# Convert features list to numpy array
features = np.asarray(features_list)

# Convert labels list to numpy array
labels = np.array(labels_list)



features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, shuffle = True, random_state = 42)

I have 16gb of RAM and the .npy files are (9221) in total, having the shape of (298, 32, 32, 3) with the size of 895kb each. Is something wrong or missing in my code? and Is there any way to load these npy files without taking too much of memory?
I've tried this potential solution:
del data
gc.collect()
but it doesn't work in my case. Hoping for a kind answer.

Just checking: Your raw data is already 9 GB? And your total memory is only 16 GB? From which you need to deduct all the memory used for the OS and other programs? And then there's Python overhead?  At first glance, this isn't strange.

Thankyou for the comment. So, is there nothing wrong or missing in the code?

features_list is about 9 GB, and features is another 9 GB. That's more than 16GB.
It might be easier to read one .npy file directly into features, reshape it to add an extra dimension of size 1, resize that dimension to 9221, and then assign the next 9220 files to slices of features. This means you're assigning 895 kB at a time, and using only a little more than 9 GB.
The trick with numpy and big data is to keep everything in numpy, and not in raw Python lists, and certainly not convert between the two.

Or, without changing the npy at all (we don't know why those 9221 files are there, and if that is a choice), simply allocate a feature (features=np.empty((9221,298,32,32,3), dtype=np.uint8)), and then fill it for i in range(9221): features[i] = np.load(f'video{i}.npy'). (I am surmising the np.uint8 from the name "video", and the fact that 894k=298×32×32×3, so 1 byte per number. But maybe it is np.int8 or bool)

I think this might be it. Thankyou so much for the help! I somehow get an idea of how numpy arrays actually work. Thankyou!

it seems like you're doing some machine learning / deep learning. There is a fundamental problem in your approach, rather than the code. Datasets can often go in the range of 50-100 GB, and it is usually not feasible to load everything into memory. So you usually load a particular number of data samples (called a "batch" of data) in each training iteration, and then train your model with mini-batch gradient descent.
You should do this instead:
# maintain a list of indices
idx_list = np.arange(9221)

# split the indices
train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(idx_list, test_size=0.25, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# write a function that loads a batch of data instead of all the data
# It can be the exact same function you are using now

def load_batch_of_data(batch_indices):
    frames, labels = [], []
    for index in batch_indices:
        # load a video frame
        # load a label

    # use np.stack, vstack, hstack, asarray, etc to convert into 1 array
    return np.stack(frames), np.stack(labels)


# train with some batch size that is appropriate for your memory
def train(train_idx, max_epochs, batch_size=32):
    for epoch in max_epochs:
        indices = np.random.permutation(train_indices)
        for i in range(9221 // batch_size):
            batch_indices = indices[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]
            features, labels = load_batch(batch_indices)
            # do some training operation


So it's obviously not as fast as loading everything into memory beforehand---but that is usually feasible when data sizes are not that big (<10GiB).
If your data is uint8, that should be 8440504320 bytes, or about 9GiB---so it is still actually in the feasible range of loading everything into memory. If you want to load everything into memory, you should follow the suggestion of @chrslg in the comment of another answer: preallocate a big array, and then iteratively load into it to avoid making copies.

Yes, Thankyou so much for the help! I'll keep everything in mind. Thankyou!
